# Proverbs similar to "We're not rich enough to buy cheap things"

Tags: idiom-request, proverbs

I'm looking for other proverbs similar to "We're not rich enough to buy cheap things". This is because I want to use it for a similar but a little bit different purpose. I want it to be meant that to get something valuable you must pay more than the price that is common place.

Answer (score 7):

One common adage used in AmE:

- You get what you pay for.

This means that if you pay only a little, you get cheap goods; you must pay more for higher quality.

Answer (score 2):

I'll agree with Brian Hitchcock's answer, and point out that the opposite (unrealistically trying to pay less for better quality) is

**champagne (taste or tastes) on a beer budget** where "taste" refers to preferences rather than food sensations in the mouth.

Comment: I've never heard this one. I think when it comes to proverbs, it's better to use more common ones.

Comment: I've heard this one, and I think it is interesting as an aside, but I'm not sure it's helpful in answering the question. It doesn't incorporate the idea that it can be more expensive to buy cheap things that wear out quickly than to spend more for better quality things that last.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, the thread starter gave a proverb that _does not quite_ express what he wants to express. "Champagne taste on a beer budget" comes quite close to what he is asking for.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm not sure, because the way I interpret champagne taste is wanting something you can't afford, and not necessarily getting more value for the money you spend.

Comment: This answer is good for what I want to say, the only problem is that it's not 'clean'! I would rather to find one that is not related to alcoholic drinks. Anyway +1 for the answer.

Comment: @Whelt - see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+beer+budget&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20beer%20budget%3B%2Cc0  It's common enough in some circles (specifically, American).

Comment: @ColleenV -  Please read the answer carefully. The phrase illustrates the opposite of original, and I specified the different meaning. I find contrasting meanings to be useful.